# Do you and should you rename a custom User model in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.9

I am creating a new User model for my Django project. I have been many people calling their custom user model, XXXUser and custom user manager, XXXUserManager.

I was wondering if there is a reason for this.  Can you just create a custom user and still call it User?  Does this create conflicts in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can. But for readability purposes it's better to do it `XxxUser`, if you see `XxxUser` you are instantly understand that this is custom one. And you need to keep in mind that you should replace some code that is common for base usage.

Such as(should be replaces)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Should be

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

And if you reference to `User` model in your *models.py* you need to

```
from django.conf import settings

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field = models.RetationField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Also do not forget to set your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` that references to your custom one

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom user models then take a look at subclassing either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` detailed in the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

You can then do something like the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class KarmaUser(AbstractUser): 
    karma = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("karma"), default=0, blank=True)

# Inside project/settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles.KarmaUser"
```

You could also create your own completely seperate model and tie it back to the user with a one-to-one relationship

Comment: I guess my questions is why do I need to rename it to KarmaUser? Can I just keep it as: class User(AbstractUser): ...

Comment: Regardless of whether there are implications to doing so, I'd avoid naming a custom User model user because it could confuse people reading over your code base, you don't really want to mess with Django's built in naming conventions by naming something after a Builtin with different behaviour. It could also be a reserved word in certain DB schemas (I think).... You'll have to try it for yourself